# error in jquery.awesome-cropper.js:77 Uncaught TypeError: $imagesContainer.modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

while selecting an image getting an error of modal, in jquery.awesome-cooper.js.

error in this line.
    $imagesContainer.modal().on('shown', function() {